# How to make a banner show from a click (Angular 5+)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have a componentA and I have a drop-down menu where when a user clicks on the link, it will show the banner which is in a another component called ComponentB.

ComponentA

```
<div class="sendFeedback" (click)="showBanner()"><p>Send Feedback</p></div>
```

ComponentB <--currently this works based on Timer, but I would like it to work on a click

```
  public showFeedbackBanner(type) {
    if (type) {
      this.sendPositive();
    }

    this.showFeedback = true;
  }
```

Comment: the html template is invoking `showBanner` on click, but the method name in the your typescript component is `showFeedbackBanner`. The html template is also not passing the `type` argument. Would this be the cause?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you have to add a `*ngIf="showFeedback"` to the component B, and `(click)="showFeedback = !showFeedback"` to component A button.

So, when you click on button, will toggle showFeedback variable (boolean).

Answer (score 0):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'component-a',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  template: `
  <component-b [showFeedback]="showFeedback"></component-b>

  <p (click)="showFeedback=!showFeedback"> Send Feedback </p>
  `,
})
export class ComponentA {
  showFeedback:boolean=false;
}



@Component({
  selector: 'component-a',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  template: `
    <div *ngIf="showFeedback">Some Baner Component</div>
  `,
})
export class ComponentB {
  @Input('showFeedback') showFeedback;
}
```

Since the event handler is in `Component A`, `Input` Binding should be passed to `Component B` to target the element element for changing its behavior.

**[showFeedback]="showFeedback"**

**@Input('showFeedback') showFeedback;**